# PyCUDA: "import pycuda.gl as cuda_gl", how to find pycuda.gl?

Tags: cuda

everyone. Recently I am learning pyCUDA. When I execute the "SobelFilter.py" example in SDK, I get the error as follows.

```
File "SobelFilter.py", line 31, in <module>
    import pycuda.gl as cuda_gl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycuda-2011.1.2-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pycuda/gl/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise ImportError("PyCUDA was compiled without GL extension support")
ImportError: PyCUDA was compiled without GL extension support
```

So can anyone help to solve it? I am new to pyCUDA, and last time Ely helped me a lot. I hope he can see it this time again.

Answer (score 1):

The Error says: PyCUDA was compiled without GL extension support.

How did you compile PyCUDA ? which OS ? do You have the opengl-dev packages ?

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild PyCUDA with

```
CUDA_ENABLE_GL = True
```

in siteconf.py

Comment: Or in case you are using configure script: `./configure.py --cuda-enable-gl`, it will set the flag in siteconf automatically